# how to dynamically add and delete functions from a solidity contract on the fly

Tags: solidity, remix

Hi I am creating an app similar to this https://cointool.app/createToken/eth
.

What puzzles me is that in other config section it gives user the ability to choose what functions they wanna use.

From my understanding you will have to clone a contract to create a token, so what's written in that original copy can't be changed, therefore in order to give users the ability to add functions you will have to have copies of contracts that meets each scenario, which is a lot, in this case it's 2^5 = 32 copies of contracts

Is that the only way? Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: you can implement it via redirects using `call()` but this is going to cost additional 9,000 gas for each call to the User

Comment: Check out Delegatecall.  Point your immutable  main contract to another contract that has the program logic.  If you need new logic point your main contract to a new contract.

Comment: If you look at the advanced setting they are quite configurable. It doesn't seem that they have predeployed contract, I'd guess they have templates for each part that they combine to create the solidity source, then compile and deploy.